# Compiler: too many arguments given despite that all are given

Tags: go

I want to use the struct `DataResponse` as parameter for `JSON()` to respond with the user. By initializing an instance of `DataResponse` I get the error message, that too many arguments are given, but gave all that are necessary.

```
type DataResponse struct {
    Status int         `json:"status"`
    Data   interface{} `json:"data"`
}

func GetUser(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    user := models.User{}
    // Fetching user from db

    resp := DataResponse(200, user)
    JSON(rw, resp) // rw is the ResponseWriter of net/http
}
```

The following error message is thrown by the compiler:

```
too many arguments to conversion to DataResponse: DataResponse(200, user)
```

`DataResponse` requires two parameters that are given and `Data` is an interface so it should accept `models.User` as datatype.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> ```
> resp := DataResponse(200, user)
> ```

The syntax is wrong. Try curly braces for struct initialization:

```
resp := DataResponse{200, user}
                    ^         ^
```

Comment: I was too focussed on the parameters that I didn't saw the missing curly braces.