# Too many arguments in conversion to DataResponse

Tags: go

Im am trying to make function that acts like a constructor

```
type DataResponse struct {
    status  int
    message string
    data    interface{}
}

func (d DataResponse) New(status int, message string, data interface{}) DataResponse {
    return DataResponse{
        status,
        message,
        data,
    }
}
```

Now that I call it  like this

```
func ReadUser(db *database.Database) fiber.Handler {
    return func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        id := IDFromParams(c)
        var User model.User
        result := db.First(&User, id)
        if result.Error != nil {
            panic(result.Error)
        }
        return SendDataResponse(c, DataResponse(
            200,
            "User read",
            &User,
        ))
    }
}
```

Vscode shows me the following error

```
too many arguments in conversion to DataResponse
```

Why is it saying that?

Comment: Do you have already see this?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30358371/2270041

Comment: But he doesn't use a constructor so it is a different question

Comment: If `DataResponse` is a type, then `DataResponse( ... )` is a conversion expression, not a "constructor" invocation.

Comment: Note that Go does not have the concept of "static" methods. If you wanted to, you could do `DataResponse.New(DataResponse{}, 200, "User read", &User)` but as you can see that's not very nice. Usually constructors are written as plain functions like `NewDataResponse(...) DataResponse` and not as methods.

Comment: "I made a type [...] and added a contructor" no you didn't. Please take the Tour  of Go for  language fundamentals and do not use fiber.

Comment: Aah okay in that case I think it would be better to close the question.

Comment: @Volker what's the issue with fiber though? Never used it, nor do I ever intend to, I'm just curious whether it was but a general remark or whether fiber actually has issues like iris, as some claim, has.

Comment: @mkopriva Fiber uses fasthttp for no real reason except, well, I don't know, "faster than net/http". At the expense of dividing the eco system (and not having HTTP/2, and ...)

Comment: I see, thanks @Volker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor in Go does not work like in C++, Java, etc.

If I'd want to create a constructor in Go it would look like this:

```golang
type DataResponse struct {
    status  int
    message string
    data    interface{}
}

func NewDataResponse(status int, message string, data interface{}) DataResponse {
    return DataResponse{
        status,
        message,
        data,
    }
}
```

to be called with:

```golang
resp := NewDataResponse(200, "User read", &User)
```

You do not need a constructor though as you can create an instance of a struct with:

```golang
resp := DataResponse{
    status:  200,
    message: "User read",
    data:    &User,
}
```

Sometimes constructors make sense if you want to simplify usage (e.g. setting default values) or initialise internals.

In your case, if you'd need to initialize `DataResponse` from another package, you would not be able to do it without a constructor as all it's fields are private.